# Using Conditional Formatting to alter another sheet based on a string

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I've been working on a dashboard in Google Sheets. When I select a text criterion from a dropdown on the dashboard (say the location `Manhattan`) I want to be able to highlight a row corresponding to that same text on a different sheet. The idea is that the dropdown is generated from the same sheet and I want to have this easier to read as a result.

I read from [Conditional Formatting from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735025/conditional-formatting-from-another-sheet) that it's not possible (at least a few years ago) directly to reference another sheet in Conditional Formatting except by utilizing the INDIRECT function. From what I can tell, this does not work with text.

Is there a way around this or should I rethink how to make my highlighting a possibility?

I know I could just have the text in the dropdown change on a portion of the sheet and then base the conditional on that, but I was hoping to simplify this. This will affect three other sheets when I'm done with it, so less would be more. I have not experimented with add-ons at all at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dropdown is in A1 and row length in other sheet is A:Z then select ColumnsA:Z in the other sheet and Format > Conditional formatting..., for Format cells if... select *Custom formula is* and enter:

```
=$A1=indirect("Dashboard!A1")
```

with formatting of choice then click <kbd>Done</kbd>.