# How to Apply Conditional Formatting based on other sheet value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a sheet with data, in Sheet1 I have data in column M (Text data value "Done") so now I try to apply Conditional Formatting on my Sheet2 column K2:K if Sheet1 Column M have value "Done".
I tried this formula:

```
=Search("Done",indirect("Sheet1!M2:M"),0)
```

also this one:

```
=search("Done",Sheet1!$M2:$M)
```

but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to highlight the entire column but just on a line-by-line basis, could you try with the following formula :

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&CELL("address",M1))="Done"`

It worked for me when applying this as a conditional formatting rule in column K of  sheet 2 and adding manually-created sample data in column K of sheet 1.

You might also want to check this if you were expecting another behaviour :
[Conditional Formatting from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735025/conditional-formatting-from-another-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

if your **Sheet1** looks like this:

[image: 0]

---

then all you need is:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!M2:M")="Done"
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KRc8ctUYXqTWC1i3XdpzSaPvA3T3Y8OTzZ0d7HW8FPA/copy)

Comment: Thanks, now I have another way to do this.