# How can I use Conditional Formatting to colour cells on one sheet using information from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, formatting, conditional-statements

I need to make Google sheets calendar respond to a conditional formatting formula that takes data from each month's sheet into the yearly sheet. Basically, I want to enter information into the monthly sheets and have that week/day change colour on the yearly sheet. In the image examples, we booked a job in June from June 21-25. I have the Monthly sheets set up to highlight when something is booked. I would like the Yearly calendar sheet to reflect the same week highlighted. In the example, I have highlighted it manually as I haven't found a way to automate the process.
Can anyone help me, please?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wc42B4REgbwtfTD1FDJGuxWllsG0Ptbm6sgc1HhFiWc/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Examples]

Comment: See [Conditional Formatting from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753889/13045193).

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Formatting from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735025/conditional-formatting-from-another-sheet)