# Google Spreadsheets: Conditional formating based on text in another sheet

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a conditional formatting statement based on if a cell is filled with text on another sheet.

For example:

Sheet1 needs to change color of the cell A1 to blue if Sheet2 has text in cell A1

I used a couple of techniques as suggested in other stackoverflow questions, such as:
[Conditional Formatting from another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735025/conditional-formatting-from-another-sheet) (I cant find out how to do some sort of regexmatch in this statement)

I thought of some sort of line as (as a custom formula in conditional formatting):

`A1(REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(Sheet2!A1), ""),1 ,0))`

but that doesnt work.

Hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=A1=NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")))
```

Comment: Thank you! This sort of worked. The correct line of code I needed was: `=A1=(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")))`