# How would I search a spreadsheet for one value in a list of values?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

This seems like it should be easier than it is. I want to find a spreadsheet search function that will let me search for a single term in multiple cells.

I have a list of staffers by date. And a second list that shows their primary work site.

So the first list is this:

```
9/23/23 Padmé Amidala
9/24/23 Ben Solo
9/25/23 Luke Skywalker
9/26/23 Luke Skywalker
9/27/23 Chewbaca    
9/28/23 Jabba the Hutt
9/29/23 Chewbacca
```

And then a second list that has primary work assignments by name:

```
Jabba the Hutt  Ice Cream Counter
Padmé Amidala   Pizza Oven
Ben Solo    Pizza Oven
Luke Skywalker  Pizza Oven
Chewbacca   Pizza Oven
```

I'd like to be able to use conditional formatting to color code them by their primary work assignments (So Pizza Oven folks are blue and Ice Cream Counter folks are pink). To do that, I need to know which roster their name is on.

I can use a lookup to find their individual assignments, but was trying to find a way to just confirm whether any one staffer is on the Pizza Oven list or the Ice Cream Counter list. Neither `=FIND()` nor `=SEARCH()` will search multiple cells for a match.

Is there a standard spreadsheet formula that will confirm the existence of a search term in multiple cells?

Update: As requested, I'm adding a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUQ7kglIuf-bsvVTVJg2zQYrwirjWCH-UXlWxnx1pbk/edit?usp=sharing) with demo data. You an also see, there, what I have tried:

- Option 1: I can use a `=LOOKUP()` to find the name of the appropriate site for each staffer, and then either `=EXACT()` or `=MATCH()` to do the actual conditional formatting. This works, but I have to populate a "Site" column for each.
- Option 1A: Incorporate the `=LOOKUP()` into the conditional formatting. I'm able to nest the formulas and get the expected TRUE/FALSE statements, but while `=EXACT(C1,"Pizza")` works to color all the rows where I've populated, if I try to nest the formulas, eg. `=EXACT(LOOKUP(B1,'Staffing Roster'!A$1:B$72, 'Staffing Roster'!B:B),"Pizza")` I see an `Invalid Formula` error.
- Option 2: I tried a few variations on `=SEARCH()`, `=MATCH()` and `=EXACT()` but none of them work.
- Option 3: Trying to use `=VLOOKUP()` with `=INDIRECT()` but getting errors.

There are a few different "Roster" tabs that have the roster either alphabetical by name (which is needed for `=LOOKUP()`) or grouped by site.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and thought there was specific instruction not to link to a sheet.

Comment: @century-tuna answer should work for the setup in the sample sheet `=VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT("'Staffing Roster'!A:B"),2,) = "Pizza"`

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION:**

Based from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735025/conditional-formatting-from-another-sheet):

> a custom formula in conditional formatting does not directly support cross-sheet references.
>
> But cross-sheet references are supported INDIRECT-ly

Following the suggestion, you can use this formula sample on your conditional formatting using Custom Formula:

Use this for evaluating their work assignments:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT("Sheet3!$A$1:$B$5"),2,false) = "Pizza Oven",true,false)

=IF(VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT("Sheet3!$A$1:$B$5"),2,false) = "Ice Cream Counter",true,false)
```

These formulas should be added separately as such:

[image]

**SAMPLE:**

[image]

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you, or respond back if you need any further clarifications